# How do I make the button change color when active

Tags: html, css, reactjs

There are two buttons in my sidebar. I want to make my button blue when it's clicked and to remain blue until the other button is clicked. It shouldn't change back to the old color when we click on the body or anywhere else but only when I click the other button.

It would also be nice if someone can show me if those sidebar buttons to turn white again when clicked on the create new button on the navbar.

code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-feynman-2tvy5

css for the buttons

```
.sideButton {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background-color: rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.14);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 28px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 28px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 28px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.sideButton:focus,
.sideButton:active,
.sideButton.active {

  background-color: blue;
}
.sideButton2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 55px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 28px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 28px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 28px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.sideButton2:focus,
.sideButton2:active,
.sideButton2.active {

  background-color: blue;
}
```

the react files where the button is located

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { Nav, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

import "../App.css";
export default class LeftBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="nav">
          <ul>
            <li className="list-item">
              <Link to="/about">
                <input
                  type="button"
                  className="sideButton sideBarText"
                  value="Dashboard"
                />
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="list-item">
              <Link to="/">
                <input
                  type="button"
                  className="sideButton2 sideBarText2"
                  value="People"
                />
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if you want this 'It shouldn't change back to the old color when we click on the body or anywhere else but only when I click the other button.', I don't think it is possible using css, you can use javascript to add and remove classes.

Comment: how do I add javascript code inside the react file and where do I exactly place this?

Comment: hey @henrydoe check my answer which helps you in your project

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-glade-du5kc

Comment: it's not working.. I fixed it using the below answer. Can you see that the box shadow for the navigation and main content area is not uniform, there's a gap in between, any chance you can help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own kind of link that would be in sync with url

```
import {
  Link,
  withRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

function NavInput({ value, className, to, location }) {
  let isActive = to === location.pathname;
  return (
    <Link to={to}>
      <input
        type="button"
        className={className + (isActive ? " active" : "")}
        value={value}
      />
    </Link>
  );
}

const NavInputLink = withRouter(NavInput);
```

and then your leftBox.js would be

```
export default class LeftBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="nav">
          <ul>
            <li className="list-item">
              <NavInputLink
                to="/about"
                value="Dashboard"
                className="sideButton sideBarText"
              />
            </li>
            <li className="list-item">
              <NavInputLink
                to="/"
                value="People"
                className="sideButton2 sideBarText2"
              />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Please check https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-firefly-cq0hr

Comment: Thanks man. It worked. Can you explain a little what you did there in the NavInputLink component?

Comment: Basically I'm just comparing "to" that you pass (e.g. /about) with current browser url which is location.pathname. If they are same then you add " active" to your class. This way you don't care about changing active class, it is automatically synced with URL, meaning it will work while you click on buttons but also when you initially refresh browser, correct button will be active.

Comment: I tried to do the same with the textBox.js components, I have put the navinputlink component in that file too but it isn't working and doesn't show the text but a ugly button so I removed navinputlink and used link, it does show the text, but it doesn't work too when clicked. I want to change the fontsize when I click on any of the buttons. But it's not showing appropriately. The main files to look here are layout.js and textbox.js and the app.css(mainCom and mainComS classes). Can you please take a look and show me the right direction? https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-lederberg-bipgj

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do? You've just copy/paste NavInputLink in your textbox.js but you are not using it in your render method at all - you are still using Link component.

Comment: I want to do the same thing as we did before. Before I wanted to change the button color to blue and now I want to change the font size from 24px to 40px when the button is active

Comment: also the react router is not working for them. when you click on the links, they should show the components below the navigation panel but it doesn't show anything when clicked

Answer (score 1):

#### the easiest way to make this possible is using NavLink

### leftBox.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  NavLink
} from "react-router-dom";

import { Nav, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

import "../App.css";
export default class LeftBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      button: false
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="nav">
          <ul>
            <li className="list-item">
              <NavLink
                to="/about"
                className="sideButton"
                activeClassName="active_navbar"
                exact
              >
                 Dashboard
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="list-item">
              <NavLink
                to="/"
                className="sideButton2"
                activeClassName="active_navbar"
                exact
              >
                People
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

### Change CSS

```css
.sideButton {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background-color: rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.14);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  /* show a hand cursor on hover; some argue that we
  should keep the default arrow cursor for buttons */
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 28px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 28px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 28px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.sideButton:focus,
.sideButton:active,
.sideButton.active {
  /* background-color: rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.14); */
  background-color: blue;
}
.sideButton:selected {
  background-color: #007bff;
}

.sideButton2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 55px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 28px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 28px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 28px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.sideButton2:focus,
.sideButton2:active,
.sideButton2.active {
  /* background-color: rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.14); */
  background-color: blue;
}

.active_navbar {
  background-color: blue;
}
.leftMain {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.rightMain {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.7rem 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px var(--primary-color);
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;

  /* box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); */
  box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8),
    -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 9px 0px 0px white, 0 -9px 0px 0px white,
    12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8),
    -12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
}
.navbar a {
  color: #2076d9;
  padding: 0.45rem;
  margin: 0 0.25rem;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.navbar .welcome span {
  margin-right: 0.6rem;
}
/* dashButton {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
dashButton::after {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
} */

@media (min-width: 768px) #dashboardpills .nav-item .nav-link {
  max-height: 42px;
  opacity: 0.25;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 42px;
}
a:not([href]):not([tabindex]) {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-pills .nav-link {
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
.nav-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
a {
  color: #007bff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet li {
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
.nav {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.titleName {
  font-family: Poppins;
}

.sideBarText {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.sideBarText2 {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.createNew {
  height: 40px;
  width: 153px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* background-color: #2076d9; */
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to top,
    #d83f91,
    #d0409b,
    #c743a5,
    #bb47af,
    #ae4bb8
  );
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.signOut {
  border: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #eb3941,
    #f15e64,
    #e14e53,
    #e2373f
  );
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(242, 97, 103, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.mainCom {
  height: 56px;
  width: 68px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 56px;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mainComS {
  height: 42px;
  width: 255px;
  opacity: 0.25;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 42px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mainComS2 {
  height: 42px;
  width: 200px;
  opacity: 0.25;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Poppins;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 42px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.conMain {
  height: 130vh;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8),
    -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 9px 0px 0px white, 0 -9px 0px 0px white,
    12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8),
    -12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

### You will get your all solution in it

You can change your class dynamically. Hitt the upvote if use like it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("li").click(function() {

      if($(this).siblings('li').find('input').hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).siblings('li').find('input').removeClass('active');
        $(this).find('input').addClass('active');
      }

    });

  });
```

```css
li {
        list-style: none;
        padding-right: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      li .btn {
          padding: 7px 20px;
          background: #fff;
          border: 1px solid #000;
          font-size: 16px;
          color: #000;
          outline: none;
      }
      li .btn.active {
          color: #fff;
          background: #000;
          border: 1px solid #000;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input class="btn active" type="button" name="Button 1" value="btn1">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class="btn" type="button" name="Button 3" value="btn2">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one of your ways to accomplish this,  you can do is, make a state in your class, like:

```
state={mycolor:"red"};
```

And your button be like:

```
<button style={{color:this.state.mycolor}}
 onClick={()=>this.colorhandler()}>click here</button>
```

And in your class define your colorhandler

```
colorhandler(){
this.setState({mycolor:"blue"});
 }
```

And when you click on the button the color will change,

hope you get the idea and works for you

**update**
If you want keep your CSS files you can change code like this:

```
state={myclassname:"btn active"};


< button class={ this.state.myclassname}
     onClick={ ()=>this.Classhandler()}> click here </ button>

Classhandler(){
this.setState({myclassname:"btn deactive"});
 }
```

Comment: it didn't work. can you edit my code sandbox.. I added your code and I got some cross origin errors.

Comment: @henrydoe I just tested it and then wrote it, you should remove your other CSS files.  At this moment I am with mobile, will test it on your code as soon as I can

Comment: but I would need my css file because the positioning, border radius and all other things will mess up